# Apache Spark-Get All Field Names From Nested Arbitrary JSON Files

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-spark, avro, parquet

I have run into a somewhat perplexing issue that has plagued me for several months now.  I am trying to create an Avro Schema (schema-enforced format for serializing arbitrary data, basically, as I understand it) to convert some complex JSON files (arbitrary and nested) eventually to Parquet in a pipeline.

I am wondering if there is a way to get the superset of field names I need for this use case staying in Apache Spark instead of Hadoop MR in a reasonable fashion?

I think Apache Arrow under development might be able to help avoid this by treating JSON as a first class citizen eventually, but it is still aways off yet.

Any guidance would be sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Define "arbitrary" with respect to your complex JSON files.

Comment: @DavidGriffin Certainly, thanks for inquiring.  The Individual JSON files contain an arbitrary combination on known object resources which are also heavily nested.  I hope that helps and can provide additional detail if needed.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro